# Twilio always returns "in-progress" regardless of actual outcome

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to detect if the number being dialed answers the phone or not, but it always returns the status **CallStatus** as "**in-progress**". For example when I get a call from Twilio and I let the phone ring I still see

```
[CallStatus] => in-progress
```

This is the code snippet I use to generate the call. As you can see I subscribed to **answered**, so I'm not even sure why it pings the statusCallback URL, but it does.

```
$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($this->account_sid, $this->auth_token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    $to,
    $from,
    array(
        'statusCallback' => 'https://statusCallbackURL',
        'statusCallbackEvent' => ['answered'],
        'fallbackUrl' => '',
        'url' => '',
        'timeout' => 60,
    )
);
```

Comment: There's not a status event for answered ([ref](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132547-What-are-the-Possible-Call-Statuses-and-What-do-They-Mean-)).

Comment: @c1moore thank you. Are you positive? I see 'You can use the StatusCallbackEvent parameter to get notifications when a call reaches the initiated, ringing, answered and completed states.' on https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132267-Tracking-the-Status-of-an-Outbound-Twilio-Voice-Call

Comment: This doc seems to list those statuses too (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#get-call-status-events-during-a-call), so I'm going to guess my original link was just out of date.  I haven't done a ton with statuses outside of listening for just disconnected events tbh.

Comment: @c1moore got it thanks! I read in a few places that it's because Twilio gets the incorrect status directly from the Telco, so they send over incorrect values... Support is still AWOL so will wait for them to confirm.

Comment: That's what I was seeing, too.  You might be able to find a workaround by listening to the audio stream for the outbound call, but I don't know if you'll be able to get that info from the status events directly.

Comment: @c1moore in my case i'm going to ask the end user to press a button to confirm that a connection was made. Think it's the most surefire way

Comment: Are you testing by calling another Twilio Number? Did you try dialing different numbers to see if you get different results?

Comment: @Alan tried a few numbers on 2 different carriers, but same result unfortunately

Comment: But not Twilio numbers you're calling, correct?

Comment: @Alan nope, calling regular north american cell phone numbers

Comment: Trying using `completed` (which is the default) instead, which then returns different values. From the documentation, the call is completed, regardless of the termination status (which can be busy, cancelled, completed, failed, or no-answer). If no StatusCallbackEvent is specified, completed is fired by default. I tested it out and when I set the timeout to a low value, 'CallStatus' returned, `no-answer`. The `url` parameter is hit when the call is answered. Try using API Explorer, https://www.twilio.com/console/api-explorer/voice/calls/create, to see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you, can pls you post it as a reply so I'll accept it, on our end we ended up asking people to click a button to confirm the call because Twilio does seem to have difficulties identifying when people answer don't answer because of the responses they gets from telcos